How do u connect to a socks5 proxy with password and login
I feel like for weeks I have been going in circles and I’m desperate I’m not sure what I need to connect it. When I say I’m a virgin to all of this I mean I have never connected a proxy to anything Ubuntu is my first thing ever I’m working in a fresh ubuntu vm bottom line I need to connect to a socks5 proxy with password and login

Please have a read through this document and edit the question. Critical details are missing. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
